# Unable to format a newly bought pendrive in Disks utility

Tags: usb, usb-drive, gnome-disk-utility

I recently bought a pendrive (HP 32 GB). When I plugged it into my PC, it didn't make any changes. I then decided to format it, but was unable to do it. The attached image shows the output of the Disks utility when I formatted the pendrive in FAT32.

[image: Screenshot of Disks utility's error message]

The same output was obtained when I tried to do it in NTFS format; just changed VFAT to NTFS.

Another thing I noticed is that my pendrive is 32 GB (labeled) but Disks utility says that it is 34 GB.

I am new to Linux but can copy and paste terminal commands.

Comment: Welcome, try with GParted.

Comment: Install gparted with `sudo apt install gparted`